# How to return Unauthorized response while overriding AuthorizationMiddleware in Ocelot & .Net WebApi

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, .net-5, api-gateway, asp.net-authorization, ocelot

I'm tring to override Ocelot AuthorizationMiddleware using a OcelotPipelineConfiguration in .NET 5 WebApi. This is my code:

#### UPDATED

**Configure**

```cs
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, IAuthorizationService authorizationService)
        {
            if (env.EnvironmentName == Environments.Development)
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseAuthentication();

            var configuration = new OcelotPipelineConfiguration
            {
                AuthorizationMiddleware = async (ctx, next) =>
                {

                    if (! await authorizationService.IsValid(ctx))
                    {
                        ctx.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
                        await ctx.Response.WriteAsync("Some Error !");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        await next.Invoke();
                    }
                },
            };
            app.UseOcelot(configuration).Wait();
        }
```

#### UPDATED

**ConfigureServices**

```cs
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            string AuthenticationKey = "AuthenticationKey";
            services.AddLogging();
            services.AddAuthentication(option =>
            {
                option.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                option.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            }).AddJwtBearer(AuthenticationKey, option =>
             {
                 option.RequireHttpsMetadata = true;
                 option.SaveToken = true;
                 option.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                 {
                     IssuerSigningKey =
                         new SymmetricSecurityKey(
                             Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Configuration.GetSection("SecretKey").Value)),
                     ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                     ValidateIssuer = false,
                     ValidateAudience = false
                 };

                 //option.ForwardSignIn

             });

            services.AddHttpClient<IAuthorizationService, AuthorizationService>();

            services.AddScoped<IJWTHelpers, JWTHelpers>();

            services
                .AddOcelot()
                .AddDelegatingHandler<HeaderDelegatingHandler>();

            services.AddMvc();
        }
```

As you can see, in some situations I need to return an immediate response like **Unauthorized**, but my code always return a *500 Internal Server Error* to Postman.
I searched a lot and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56772376/how-can-i-stop-a-request-in-ocelots-preauthenticationmiddleware) question. But I cann't find **Errors.Add** method in HTTPContext.
Is there any Idea to return immediate Unauthorized response?

Comment: Could you share full steps of how are you implemented the authentication step on your startup.cs so that we could get into this.

Comment: I updated the question. You can also find my code in [THIS](https://github.com/tarafdarmansour/OcelotWithCustumJWTAuthorization) repository. @Md Farid Uddin Kiron

Comment: May I know in which scenario you usually encounter unauthorize error?

Comment: As you can see `await authorizationService.IsValid(ctx)` try to validate my context. In this method I extract **Authorization** header to access user claims and HTTPContext.Request.Path as a resource that user want to access. We send these two parameters to my ahtorization service. If the user not authorized to access that resource I should return _unauthorize error_ .

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69084487/2557855

Comment: Dear @Artur , actually it's the correct answer.  Thank you man.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the correct answer by @Artur comment.
I replaced

```
    ctx.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
    await ctx.Response.WriteAsync("Some Error !");
```

in **Configure** Method with this one:

```
    ctx.Items.SetError(new UnauthorizedError("your custom message"));
    return;
```

Comment: works like a charm, thx, I was on the same path, but adding the error like you shown solved my probleme