# Return unauthorized in Ocelot API Gateway Middleware

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, ocelot

A this moment, i've an Ocelot API Gateway in my microservice, but i recently i was looking how to invalidate a JWT, and the best way to do this in my project is using a blacklist, so i decided to use a middleware pre authorization to check in my Redis cache the list of invalid JWT. I've looked for solutions to force return a 401 with custom message if the token is in the cache, but i can't find a functional solution. Below is my try:

```cs
public async void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, IDistributedCache cache) {
    if (env.IsDevelopment()) {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }

    app.UseRouting();

    app.UseCors();

    app.UseAuthentication();

    app.UseAuthorization();

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => {
        endpoints.MapGet("/", async context => {
            await context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello World!");
        });
    });

    var configuration = new OcelotPipelineConfiguration {
        PreAuthorizationMiddleware = async (ctx, next) => {
            string token = ctx.Request.Headers["Authorization"].ToString().Replace("Bearer ", "");

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(token)) {
                string blacklist = await cache.GetStringAsync(token);

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(blacklist)) {
                    ctx.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
                    await ctx.Response.WriteAsync("Custom Message");

                    return;
                }
            }

            await next.Invoke();
        }
    };

    await app.UseOcelot(configuration);
}
```

Can someone help me? The solutions i've tried only returns HTTP status code 500 or always 401.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Once you are in Ocelot's pipeline, you have to play Ocelot's game. It uses special objects and extension methods on `HttpContext.Items` dictionary to pass data between middlewares. Specifically for errors it has 2 extension methods `SetError` and `UpsertErrors`. So you need to add this after checking the black list:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(blacklist))
{
    ctx.Items.SetError(new UnauthorizedError("your custom message"));
    return;
}
```

Comment: Your solution worked but instead of recieving 401 unauthorized, the response is a 403 forbidden, in my debug console the message is `Ocelot.Responder.Middleware.ResponderMiddleware: Warning: requestId: 40000002-0008-f900-b63f-84710c7967bb, previousRequestId: no previous request id, message: Error Code: UnauthorizedError Message: Custom errors found in ResponderMiddleware. Setting error response for request path: /my/path/here, request method: GET`.

Comment: You asked for unauthorized in subject, so I gave you solution for 403. If you want 401 - unauthenticated just use `new UnauthenticatedError` instead.

Comment: If you need 401 there maybe better way to handle revoked tokens. For example if you are using Okta for OIDC you are better use introspection instead of local token validation. For IdentityServer use Reference Tokens. Otherwise  implement custom AuthenticationHandler and perform blacklist lookup there